# why signed short extened to 4 bytes?

Tags: c, types, casting

Here I have a short program below which has done some explicit cast.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int x = 0xDEADBEEF;
    unsigned short y = 0xFFFF;
    printf("%x\n", y);

    if (x > (signed short) y)
        printf("true.\n");
    else{
        printf("false.\n");

        printf("(signed short)=%x\n", (signed short) y);
        printf("(unsigned int) (signed short)=%x\n", (unsigned int) (signed short) y);
        printf("(unsigned) (signed short)=%x\n", (unsigned) (signed short)y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I got output below.

```
Compiling the source code....
$gcc main.c -o demo 


Executing the program....
$demo

ffff
false.
(signed short)=ffffffff
(unsigned int) (signed short)=ffffffff
(unsigned) (signed short)=ffffffff
```

I'm so confused why y became 0xffffffff when it's cast to signed short. Short type should be 2 bytes rather than 4 bytes.

Comment: printf() is not a debugger.

Comment: `x > (signed short) y` may not mean what you think it does.

Comment: So for line "x > (signed short) y", y is firstly convert to 'signed short' type, which remains 0xffff (= -1) in memory. And then y is implicitly cast to 'unsigned int'. Thus y become 'int' 0xffffffff (= -1) and then 'unsigned int' 0xffffffff (= UTMax). Am I right to think in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"%x"` [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format code is for `int` and not `short`, for that you want `"%hx"`.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `short` type can be whatever size your compiler wants, within the restrictions of the C specification, so `short` variables are *not guaranteed* to be exactly 2 bytes in size.

What you are seeing is a *sign extension* caused by upcasting to a larger numeric type.

The number `0xffff` cast as a signed 2-byte number in two's complement represents the number -1.  When you cast this to a larger data type, the numeric value is what needs to be preserved, so the sign is extended; `0xffffffff` cast as a signed 4-byte number is also -1.  (`0x0000ffff` cast as a signed 4-byte number would be 65,535, which is not the same number.)